# The dependency Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

When I upgrade framework section to:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

I am getting error

> The dependency Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 does not support framework
>   .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.

With

"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools"

:  underlined

Comment: it seems like you cannot upgrade

Comment: @fireydude Unfortunately it worked in 1.0.1. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Maybe post your whole project.json file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft.Composition](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/) supports .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8 and WindowsPhone 8.1 among other targets, this means it should work.

But it doesn't target `netstandard1.x` specifically neither does it `netcoreapp1.x`, so you need to tell nuget via the import section to also restore PCL Libraries which target the platforms above:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "imports": ["dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8"]
    }
}
```

The `"portable-net45-win8"` part tells it, to also restore PCLs with .NET 4.5 and Windows 8 targets too, as they should work in 99% of all cases with .NET Core (Windows Runtime is based on System.Runtime and .NET Core is too, that's why it works).

But **NEVER** use `import` to restore non-PCL or PCL which don't support at least win8/wpa8 and net45.

#### Update for csproj:

To do that in the new `.csproj` project structure, you need to add

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;dnxcore50;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
```

instead. Optionally leave out `dotnet5.6` and `dnxcore50` when you're sure you don't use any packages which use any of these.

Comment: Works for me. Fixed a typo though. It should be `portable-net45+win8` not `portable-net45-win8`. Try deleting the nuget cache (C;\User\<Username>\.nuget) then restore from scratch. VS restart may be necessary

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I have just clean, rebuild, restart comp and now it works.
Now I am able to use .netcore1,1

Answer (score 15):

If you are dealing with csproj files you can edit them and add this line:

`<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>`

The result should look like this:

`<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>`

This is how VS converter does it when it upgrades project.json to csproj. If you need other targets, you can play around converting your project.json files to csproj files and see the output.