# ASP.NET Core CRUD tool: command not found but actually installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, code-generation

I'm learning ASP.net, so I'm reading https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code and in the section **Scaffold the movie model**, I must install and run the CRUD tool (ASP.net Core dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator). **The problem I encounter is I can't use their tool, an error is output ; however I could install it.** Below are the details.

So I'm following the three-steps tutorial to use this CRUD code generator (link given above). I quote:

> 1. Open a command window in the project directory (The directory that contains the Program.cs, Startup.cs, and .csproj files).

✔ It worked.

> 2. Install the scaffolding tool: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

✔ It worked and now if I try to re-install it, it outputs that it's already installed.

> 3. For macOS and Linux: Run the following command: `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages/Movies --referenceScriptLibraries`

It doesn't work. **Here is the output error:**

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
>   Possible reasons for this include:
>     * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
>     * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator does not exist.
>     * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

**Question : How can I debug it to make this command work?**

Comment: are you sure you run exactly `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator`? your error says:
`dotnet-dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator does not exist` so it looks like you tried to run: `dotnet dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

Comment: Yes I have run: `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages\Movies --referenceScriptLibraries` AND `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages\Movies --referenceScriptLibraries` AND `dotnet dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages\Movies --referenceScriptLibraries` - None of these three commands does work. :(

Comment: Oh, oh... "Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you will need to logout or restart your session before running the tool you installed." - i didn't read it, this is ouput by the CLI at the installation of the codegenerator.

Comment: **UPDATE:** it didn't solve my problem (I re-run my computer & Ubuntu session) with both versions 3.0.0 and 2.1.10 of the codegenerator :(...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`export PATH=$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH` was needed, as indicated for Core MVC (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code). This indication was forgotten for Core Razor . . .

Comment: I had same problem on Windows 10 system. In that case using  `set PATH=$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH` and restarting powershell should help.

Comment: Thank you. I don't work on this project anymore, so I can't test your solution. But thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the latest version might be inconsistent. try with older versions and see if there is any difference. Start with highest version before your current one and go down to find one that actually works. How to install older vesions:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version {version}`

You may find version history in the nuget page:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator/

Comment: Should I uninstall the last version of the codegenerator before using your command?:)

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Just updated my answer. try the latest which is older than your current. this sort of issue is quite frequent with core3.0 releases.

Comment: Well 1) I uninstalled it (using `dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`) then 2) I installed older version (`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 2.2.4`) but 3) I get the same error :(

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler it's a bummer. might be something else then. but just to be sure try some version in the 2.1 range before letting go :)

Comment: Same :/ (I tried with 2.1.10). I think there is a pb concerning the name of the command. In the Microsoft's documentation, it says to run: `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage` . However: after I have installed the code generator, my CLI indicates me to run: `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`. What is the correct command? None of both works however: is their any third command to run?

Comment: Oh, oh... "Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you will need to logout or restart your session before running the tool you installed." - i didn't read it, this is ouput by the CLI at the installation of the codegenerator.

Comment: **UPDATE:** it didn't solve my problem (I re-run my computer & Ubuntu session) with both versions 3.0.0 and 2.1.10 of the codegenerator :(...

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler this sort of issue can be very baffling. I'll do some further r&d and share it with you if found something similar.

Answer (score 3):

## On Windows 10

In my case the installer added the wrong path to the `Path` environment variable.
The path added was pointing to a non existing folder under Programs. It needs to point to `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.exe`.
For me the correct path was in my user folder: `~\.dotnet\tools`

You can check if the correct path was added by running: `echo $env:Path`
If the path is missing or incorrect you just need to add the correct path to the `Path` system environment variable.

You might be able to test this by using PowerShell to set your local variable: `$env:Path += ";C:\Users\<YOUR_NAME_HERE>\.dotnet\tools"`
*But I haven't tried this.*

---

### To fix it globally

1. Start typing `Environment` in the windows search and you should see the `Control panel` option to `Edit system environment variables`.
2. Click the `Environment Variables...` button in the lower right corner.
3. Under `System variables` find and select the `Path` variable, then click `Edit`.
4. Check if the path to `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.exe` is there and if not click `New` and add it.
5. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, oh... "Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you will need to logout or restart your session before running the tool you installed." - i didn't read it, this is ouput by the CLI at the installation of the codegenerator.

**UPDATE:** it didn't solve my problem (I re-run my computer & Ubuntu session) with both versions 3.0.0 and 2.1.10 of the codegenerator :(...

Comment: @Anand you should look to the bottom answer :)